# Removing a node in C# is creating a NULL

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, which I am reading into a Web API and return it as a JSON string. I want to delete some of the nodes from XML (without saving onto a file) before returning it as JSON.

**My XML file:**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "12:30">
        <price>100</price>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </Time>

    <Time Stamp= "14:50">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time> 

    <Time Stamp= "16:30">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time>     
</CurrentStatus>
```

**My Code to Remove a Node:**

```
//Read XML
XDocument xDocHistory = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");

                //Go through all the Time nodes one by one
                foreach (XElement TimeNode in xDocHistory.Descendants("Time"))
                {
                    string nodeTimeStamp = TimeNode.Attribute("Stamp").Value.ToString();

                    if(nodeTimeStamp == "16:30")
                    {
                        TimeNode.RemoveAll();
                    }

                }

                //Convert XML data into JSON string
                string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDocHistory);
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
                return Ok(json);
```

**JSON Output:**

```
"CurrentStatus": {
    "Time": [
        {
            "@Stamp": "12:30",
            "price": "100",
            "amount": "1"
        },
        {
            "@Stamp": "14:50",
            "price": "10",
            "amount": "5"
        },            
        null
    ]
}
```

**PROBLEM:** The removed node appears as **NULL** in the JSON output. How can I remove it?

Comment: Note that calling `RemoveAll` on a node doesn't remove the node itself, it removes all of its children.  So it becomes an empty node.  I'm not sure why that becomes null when serialized into JSON though.

Comment: You can't remove the node in a `foreach` loop, at least not directly.  But you can use a second `for` loop to remove "empty" nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Remove` instead of `RemoveAll`.

```
foreach (XElement timeNode in xDocHistory.Descendants("Time").ToList())
{
    string nodeTimeStamp = timeNode.Attribute("Stamp").Value;

    if (nodeTimeStamp == "16:30")
    {
        timeNode.Remove();
    }
}
```

Note `ToList()` method.

Comment: It worked but could you please explain the reason also.

Comment: Yup, this answer is too brief. From taking a quick look at it:
1) [XElement.RemoveAll](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.removeall) removes the content of the node, but not the node itself. To remove the entire node (from its parent) you have to call [XNode.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove)
2) `ToList()` makes a separate list of the `timeNode` children that you iterate, which allows you to remove them from the root `XDocument` from within `foreach`.